# A subgroup formed by elements of cyclic group raised to a power

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Given a cyclic group $G$, how do I find the index of subgroup $H = \{x^n : \forall x \in G\}$ for some fixed $n$?

I kind of figured from answers to similar questions that it should be the number of solutions to $x^n = 1$, but I can't quite connect the dots.

Comment: It's given that $H$ is a subgroup. But let $G$ be $Z^{*}_p$, $p$ is prime for concreteness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** I want to remark I'm assuming finite groups (due to the comments).

Let's first check $H = \{x^n : x \in G\}$ is a subgroup for fixed $n \geq 1$. Notice that $e^n = e$, so $e \in H$. Next, let $a \in H$. Then $a = x^n$ for some $x \in G$, and $a^{-1} = x^{-n} = (x^{-1})^n \in H$. Hence it is closed under inverses. Finally if $a, b \in H$, then $a = x^n$, $b = y^n$ for $x,y \in G$, so $ab = x^n y^n$. Now here is where we need that $G$ is cyclic (so abelian). Recall that for an abelian group we have $(ab)^2 = a^2 b^2$, since $(ab)^2 = abab = aabb = a^2b^2$. By induction, we get this holds for all $n$. Notice that we then have $x^ny^n = (xy)^n \in H$, so it is closed under multiplication. This tells us that it is a subgroup.

Now the index of a subgroup is $[G:H] = |G|/|H|$. Consider the map $f : G \rightarrow H$ defined by $f(x) = x^n$. This is clearly surjective. Let's check it is a homomorphism. We have
$$ f(xy) = (xy)^n = x^n y^n = f(x) f(y)$$
by our above remark. Finally we observe
$$\ker(f) = \{x \in G : f(x) = x^n = e\}.$$
By the first isomorphism theorem,
$$ G/\ker(f) \cong H,$$
so
$$ |G/\ker(f)| = |G|/|\ker(f)| = |H|,$$
and
$$ [G:H] = |G|/|H| = |G|/(|G|/|\ker(f)|) = |\ker(f)|.$$
Thus the index is the number of solutions to the equation $x^n = e$.

Comment: I've found this is a pretty common trick in group theory -- if you want to figure out the size of something, try creating a homomorphism with a "nice" kernel (generally this is restricted by whatever property you're wanting to count).

Comment: Great, thank you! I will need to process the last part from the place you introduce $ker(f)$.
So we have an index as the number of solutions to $x^n = 1$, so we could find the order of $H$.
But could we find an order of $H$ in other terms, using just $n$ and $p$?

Comment: I want to say yes but I don't have any ideas right now (it is 5pm on a Friday where I'm at). If I think of something I'll update it.

Comment: Maybe one way to intuitively think about it is if your group is $G = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, then the number of elements in $H$ is the number of elements in $G$ minus all of the elements which are sent to the identity. I don't think subtraction is the right thing here but that's where my mind went first

Comment: By experimenting with small sets, it looks like $ord(H) = gcd(n, p−1)$ for $Z^{*}_p$, but I don't know how to justify this.

Comment: One way to maybe argue that is to think about how $x \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ can be a solution to the equation $nx = 0$. This should have some relation to gcd.

Comment: Sorry, it's $ord(H) = (p-1) / gcd(n, p−1)$. Still no proof for this.

Comment: Take a look at **Theorem 3.6** in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/cyclicgp.pdf and see if that is related.